# Required Practice Problems of Modelling Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Folks,

In differential equations there are two things:
1. Modeling (form differential equation based on physical system or real life problem)
2. Solving differential equation 
Need help for first part.

Could you please provide link to problem sets or practice set of Modeling Differential Equations?

I found on MIT OCW, however it will be helpful if you could send link other practicr sets, books.
Thanks.

Comment: Books are good too. Do you have access to a college library?

Comment: Please suggest books.